# Hide Column in List Definition

Tags: list, content-type

I have Content Type in which column have ShowInEditForm="True", As I want to show this columns in Edit form of List A. But I don't show this column in List B. I change column as below in list definition and Set ShowInEditForm="FALSE" but then also this column is appeared in edit form of List B.

I tried following code also

```
      foreach (SPField field in list.Fields)
                {
                    if ( field.StaticName =="Blank_Status")
                    {
                        field.ShowInEditForm = false;
                        field.Update();
                        list.Update(); break;
                    }
                }
```

Then also this is not working